# Convert PDF to Excel using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, itext

I'm using IText libray for do a PDF. This works, but I need generate the same document, but this time in Excel (xls). There's a way to convert a PDF using GWT or IText? If not, how can I do this? I searched and I found a library called JExcel. What is better?

Thanks for attention and help!

Comment: It's not a matter of GWT, because it should be done on server side. You may ask on Java forum. Anyway there are several solution but I suggest to use apache poi in order to write an XLS

Comment: @JFB Thanks for help! I'll search this library to write an XLS. Thanks for attention!

Comment: You can also take a look at aspose (commercial)